# Why does open /mall always match / in nginx

Tags: nginx

Why does open `/mall` always match `/` in nginx?

please help me, thanks

```
location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/share;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

location = /mall {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/mall;
        try_files $uri /mall/$uri/ /mall/index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` block must match the URI which is currently being processed. This is initially the original request, but certain directives (such as `index`, `try_files` and `rewrite`) can internally rewrite the URI and cause a different `location` to be selected.

For example, your original request of `/mall` gets internally rewritten to `/mall/index.html` by the `try_files` statement, which causes Nginx to restart the search for a matching location. The `location /` is selected to process the new URI.

The file `/usr/share/nginx/html/share/mall/index.html` probably doesn't exist, so the URI is internally rewritten (again) to `/index.html` (by the other `try_files` statement).

---

If you want all URIs beginning with `/mall` to be processed by the same `location`, use: `location /mall { ... }` (without the `=` operator). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Unless your files are located at `/usr/share/nginx/html/mall/mall/index.html` (with `mall` appearing twice), you should use `root /usr/share/nginx/html;`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first question on stackoverflow, it's solved, I'm so happy